# Node js Application running on EC2 but not accessible in browser using Nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm a newbie to Nginx. I cannot access my Node.js application that I deploy on AWS EC2 using Nginx reverse proxy. If I do `curl http://localhost:3000` I can see the application is running successfully on the server(I'm using pm2 for running node server). But when I try to access it in my browser or postman using public DNS I get the error **This site can't be reached** and the request gets timeout. Here's my Nginx configuration (I have followed a number of tutorials for this)

[image]

The configuration file is named nginx.conf and is in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled directory. If I do `sudo nginx -t` it says syntax is ok and the test is successful. Also I can see the Nginx is running using command `sudo systemctl status nginx` What could be the possible reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the problem wasn't with the Nginx configuration actually I needed to allow public access for port 80 on my ec2 instance which is blocked by default. I allowed port 80 and everything is working fine. This [blog](https://technodecode.com/cant-access-ec2-instance-from-browser/) helped me. Visit it for me details on how to enable port 80 for your ec2 instance.